# how to diagonally reduce box size when scroll down

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(function(){
var navIsBig = true;
var $nav = $('#header_nav');

$(document).scroll( function() {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();

    if ( value > 50 && navIsBig ){
        $nav.animate({height:45},"medium");
        $('.box').animate({height:36},"medium");
        $('.box').animate({width:78},"medium");
        navIsBig = false;

    }
    else if (value <= 50 && !navIsBig ) {
       $nav.animate({height:80},"medium");
         $('.box').animate({height:53},"medium");
        $('.box').animate({width:104},"medium"); 
        navIsBig = true;
    }
});
});
```

Here box reduce its size, first it height and then its width. But i want to reduce its size diagonally...

```
http://jsfiddle.net/9fact/466/
```

Comment: Put the height and width together like: http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/9fact/468/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can animate both properties:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fact/467/)

```
$('.box').animate({height:36, width:78});
```